# Font-awesome some icons missing

Tags: html, font-awesome

I'm going crazy with this issue. I want to show 8 icons on a page, but only 4 of them are showing up. I have looked up [this for help](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting#im-hosting-fonts-on-my-server-and-icons-dont-show-up), but I got nothing useful. I checked also on StackOverflow but didn't get anything useful either.

The full code is [here](http://habitbuild.altervista.org/test/).

And this is how I see the icons:

[image]

I get this in localhost and uploaded it to `altervista`. I get this with Chrome, Firefox and Vivaldi. I get this with local fa files and with the CDN. The icons that aren't visible are missing the `:before` but I don't know why. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using icons (e.g. [`fa-thermometer-half`](http://fontawesome.io/icon/thermometer-half/) or [`fa-free-code-camp`](http://fontawesome.io/icon/free-code-camp/)), which were introduced in version 4.7. However in your website, version 4.6.3 of FontAwesome is included (see [here](http://habitbuild.altervista.org/test/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css)). So, update your FontAwesome instance to the newest version to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the latest version of Font Awesome or copy this code into your head section.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that in CSS I was doing:

```
.icon:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome";
}
```

while it should be:

```
.icon:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}
```

Getting even a single character different causes *some* of the icons to disappear. Terrible thing.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your existing link to Font Awesome CSS using this CDN provided by Bootstrap CDN, and see the magic.

CDN: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css